# How to monitor output sound from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, audio, command-line, sound-volume

Is it possible to read current volume or frequency of outgoing sound from terminal? I am using OS X Mavericks

Comment: Volume maybe since it is one single value (a number). Displaying a frequency as a single number is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the volumes of the currently selected input, output and sound effects/alert device as a percentage value with an AppleScript one liner:

```
osascript -e "(get volume settings)"
```

which gives something similar to:

```
output volume:56, input volume:63, alert volume:28, output muted:false
```